# WSO2: How will we as developers do sizing for WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 documentation we get reference of a capacity planning sheet. (http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-capacity-planning-exercise-with-wso2-middleware-platform/)

How can we as developers get this sheet and do capacity planning for ESB implementation? Is it getting newly introduced in the Application stack?